# How to add a scrollbar to JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I have a JOptionPane full of JLabels, JTextFeilds, and Buttons, but I have so many things inside the dialogue box that it is starting to become bigger than my screen.

How do I shrink the dialog box and add a scroll bar to a JOptionPane?

I created the dialog box by creating a panel, adding the all myJLabels, JTextFeilds, and Buttons to it, adding the panel to my frame, and then:

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame1, panel1, "Please Enter Character Information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

[This is what I want to add a vertical scroll bar to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0HTI.png)

Answer (score 3):

You have part of the answer already, instead of passing `panel1` as the "message" parameter, wrap in a `JScrollPane` first

```
 JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame1, new JScrollPane(panel1), "Please Enter Character Information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Now, this might only solve part of the problem.  Since `JScrollPane` uses the `preferredSize` of the component as a bases for calculating the viewport's size, this might not help you.

You might need to implement the `Scrollable` interface be provide a smaller view rectangle via the [`Scrollable#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()).  The `JScrollPane` will then use this value as part of it's own `preferredSize` calculation